# React issue with closing tags/JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I started a course on React and I wonder why on Sublime Text 3 , while coding on React part, the closing tags don't work properly like on a JS file. The code example:

```
<div className="App">
    <h1>Hi,I'm a React App </h1>
    <p>This is really working</p>
  </div>
```

after I' the color of first h1 tag is not the same as the closed one h1 , like the program its waiting for me to close that comma after I word. How can I solve this to look / function like a normal JS file? PS: Sorry for the bad explenation.

Answer (score 2):

You should install this plugin to handle ES6 and JSX better in Sublime: https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime

Best to do it through the [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/) plugin if you haven't installed that yet.

Answer (score 0):

try naming your files .jsx instead of .js
this will help your IDE to recognize the used code.